# Custom Web service wrapper for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, service, 64-bit

Our team has found there are some things that can't be done in the out of box SharePoint web services, so we've decided to build our own web service wrapper, to wrap around Microsoft.SharePoint.dll and Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll.

My problem is, those dlls are 64 bit, so the web service must be 64 bit. When I set the project to x64 bit, asp.net throws BadImageFormatException.

Is there a working web service that can call the SharePoint 2010 native libraries that I could use to see a work around, or does anybody know a work around? Most grateful!

Answer (score 0):

How are the Microsoft dll's referenced? If they are in the web services's /bin folder, remove them there, so .net attempts to load them from the GAC.

Ive developed several wrappers and never had a 32/64 bit issue when i deployed the service to SharePoint.

Comment: Given Cassini (ASP.NET Development Server) is 32 bit, I couldn't figure out how to get it to call the SharePoint 64 bit libraries.  However, what I was able to do is create an IIS site, setting the directory of the site to the Visual Studio solution.  Then, hitting F6 (build solution) builds the solution.   Then I browse to the IIS site, http://server:4321/myservice.asmx and everything works.

Comment: There's no 64bit version of cassini, however there's a open source clone of it available at http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/ You can build your 64bit version yourself and than copy the new .exe to

"C:\Program files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0"

and overwrite the original files (of course, you'd do a backup first).

This way, you can call the SP 64bit libraries with the built-in web server. Note that this is NOT supported by microsoft, however this method works fine for me and it saves a looot of time because you don't need to publish to IIS everytime.